# Correct Restful resources with laravel

Tags: php, rest, laravel

So this is a simple question, I've searched for the answer but couldn't find anything which explains what is the correct way to write the resources in routes.

I will explain my dilemma:
assuming you have a UserController and PostController which extends it:

```
PostController extends UserController
```

now I understood the correct way to write the resources in the routes file is this:

```
//restful:
Route::resource('user', 'UserController');
Route::resource('user.post', 'PostController');
```

but when I do this, my artisan routes looks like this:

```
GET|HEAD user/{user}/post             | user.post.index      | PostController@index
GET|HEAD user/{user}/post/create      | user.post.create     | PostController@create
POST user/{user}/post                 | user.post.store      | PostController@store
GET|HEAD user/{user}/post/{post}      | user.post.show       | PostController@show
GET|HEAD user/{user}/post/{post}/edit | user.post.edit       | PostController@edit
PUT user/{user}/post/{post}           | user.post.update     | PostController@update
PATCH user/{user}/post/{post}         |                      | PostController@update
DELETE user/{user}/post/{post}        | user.post.destroy    | PostController@destroy
```

Meaning I need to send 2 parameter through the route, that's all ok, but when I write my PostController I get this problem:

```
'ErrorException' with message 'Declaration of PostController::show() should be compatible with UserController::show($id)'
```

My question is, how am I supposed to pass 2 parameters if the declaration of PostController show and UserController show,  are ought to be the same?

Comment: Are you extending `UserController` in `PostController`?

Comment: I may be wrong, but this may be an ideal time to write your own routes, rather than the `Route::resource` shortcut.

Comment: @JarekTkaczyk no, PostController extends UserController
`PostController extends UserController {`

Comment: Well.. this is what I asked, and btw it was rhethorical question ;) Now, tell me why do you do that?

Comment: @JarekTkaczyk I don't know, I thought it would make sense for post to extend the user, because it's part of the user's functionality...

Comment: @GuyMazuz Don't. It's not part of `UserController` functionality in any way. You can call it eg. `UserPostController` so you know it's part of user's functionality. Imagine this: You're talking about shapes in geometry. `Polygon extends Shape`, `Square extends Polygon`, but `Circle extends Shape` not `Polygon`. For you `Controller` (or `BaseController`) is the Shape you want to extend, not `UserController` (being `Polygon` here).

Comment: Never mind, I understand my own stupidity now :))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no reason for your `PostController` to extend your `UserController`.

The actual problem here is that the signatures for `PostController::show()` and `UserController::show()` don't match. If you're injecting models, chances are, it's because one has `Post` and the other `User`, or whatever your model names are.